# Show, that there exists a sequence of disjoint sets from $\mathcal{E}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

We are sitting with the problem below, and are currently having a hard time reaching the finishline.

Let $\mu$ and $v$ be two $\sigma$ -finite measures on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{E}) .$ Show, that there exists a sequence $\left(B_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of disjoint sets from $\mathcal{E},$ such that
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_{n}=X, \quad \text { og } \quad \mu\left(B_{n}\right), v\left(B_{n}\right)<\infty \quad \text { for alle } n
$$

Since both $\mu$ and $v$ are $\sigma$-finite measures, I make the sequences $A_n$ where $\mu(A_n)\leq\infty$ and $C_n$ where $v(C_n)\leq\infty$. I then tried to look at the intersection of these, which then is finite with respect to both measures, but I can't be sure that the union is $X$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of $A_n \cap C_m$ over all $n$ and $m$ is $X$ and this is a countable union.

[Let $\theta : \mathbb N  \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ be a bijection. Then  you can define $B_k$ as $A_n\cap B_m$ where $(n,m)=\theta (k)$].

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess we missed the fact than the union over all $n$ and $m$ is X.